# Ошибка, библиотека Flet

Tags: python, flet

Помогите решить проблему, я новичк в python, не особо разбираюсь

```
  def validate(e: ControlEvent) -> None:
         if all([InputField.value, InputField.value]):
            ElevatedButton.disable = False
         else:
            ElevatedButton.disabled = True
    
            Page.update()
    
    def sumbit(e: ControlEvent) -> None:
        print('Имя пользователя', InputField.value)
        print('Пароль', InputField.value)
    
        Page.clean()
        Page.add(
            Row(
                controls=[Text(value=f'Ку: {InputField.value}', size=20)],
                alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
            )
        )
    
    InputField.on_change = validate
    InputField.on_change = validate
    ElevatedButton.onclick = sumbit
    
    
    Page.add(
        Row(
            controls=[
                Column(
                    [
                        InputField,
                        InputField,
                        ElevatedButton
                    ]
                )
            ],
            alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
        )
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flet.app(target=main)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Code\MyProect\memos\main.py", line 157, in <module>
    Page.add(
  File "D:\Code\Python\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\page.py", line 313, in add
    with self.__lock:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute '_Page__lock'
```

Решить данную проблему сам не смог

Comment: Исправьте свой вопрос вставив код программы текстом.

Comment: Почему у вас 2 InputField. Сделайте имена разными. И еще, page пишется с маленькой буквы