# Помогите решить проблему, я новичк в python, не особо разбираюсь

Tags: python, flet

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 157, in <module>
    Page.add(
  File "D:\Code\Python\Lib\site-packages\flet_core\page.py", line 313, in add
    with self.__lock:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute '_Page__lock'
```

Код:

```
def validate(e: ControlEvent) -> None:
         if all([InputField.value, InputField.value]):
            ElevatedButton.disable = False
         else:
            ElevatedButton.disabled = True
    
            Page.update()
    
    def sumbit(e: ControlEvent) -> None:
        print('Имя пользователя', InputField.value)
        print('Пароль', InputField.value)
    
        Page.clean()
        Page.add(
            Row(
                controls=[Text(value=f'Ку: {InputField.value}', size=20)],
                alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
            )
        )
    
    InputField.on_change = validate
    InputField.on_change = validate
    ElevatedButton.onclick = sumbit
    
    
    Page.add(
        Row(
            controls=[
                Column(
                    [
                        InputField,
                        InputField,
                        ElevatedButton
                    ]
                )
            ],
            alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
        )
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flet.app(target=main)
```

Comment: Не понимаете — значит рано. Учите питон. И вы явно привели не весь код. Что он должен делать, кстати?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка, библиотека Flet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1569399/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-flet)